# Out of Memory using after 5 times of change orientation

Tags: java, android, gridview, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I am handling larges images with `900 x 900` dimension. The images are displayed by a gridview implementation. There are 5 gridviews inside ViewPager's pages. The problem after 4 times of screen orientation change, I am getting out of memory error and the images starts not displaying. The 
grow heap increases up to 43 mb. I posted the log cat errors. I am using **Universal-image-loader**.

```
File cacheDir = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "CachedImages");
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdir();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getActivity())
                .threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 3)
                //.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                .discCacheSize(3048576 * 20)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                // 1MB=1048576 *declare 20 or more size if images are more than
                // 200

                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
                // .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
                .build();
        imageLoader.init(config);
```

---

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        //.showStubImage(icon)
        //Because you reuse view for different
        //images you can see a previous image in the view while new image is loading. .resetViewBeforeLoading(true
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.content_picture)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.content_picture)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565)
        .cacheInMemory(false)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)

        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
```

---

LogCat:

```
10-22 18:19:25.856: E/SkWMTJdec(19464): wmt_jdec_header error : ERR_JDEC_NOT_SUPPORT_PROFILE!
10-22 18:19:26.028: I/dalvikvm-heap(19464): Clamp target GC heap from 48.663MB to 48.000MB
10-22 18:19:26.034: D/dalvikvm(19464): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 692K, 3% free 47698K/49031K, paused 117ms, total 123ms
10-22 18:19:26.034: I/dalvikvm-heap(19464): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1783372-byte allocation
10-22 18:19:26.171: I/dalvikvm-heap(19464): Clamp target GC heap from 48.646MB to 48.000MB
10-22 18:19:26.176: D/dalvikvm(19464): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 16K, 3% free 47681K/49031K, paused 140ms, total 140ms
10-22 18:19:26.176: E/dalvikvm-heap(19464): Out of memory on a 1783372-byte allocation.
10-22 18:19:26.177: I/dalvikvm(19464): "pool-182-thread-1" prio=4 tid=13 RUNNABLE
10-22 18:19:26.179: I/dalvikvm(19464):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41713660 self=0x5c8d92b0
10-22 18:19:26.179: I/dalvikvm(19464):   | sysTid=19664 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1551184560
10-22 18:19:26.180: I/dalvikvm(19464):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=31 stm=2 core=0
10-22 18:19:26.182: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-22 18:19:26.183: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
10-22 18:19:26.189: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
10-22 18:19:26.189: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.considerExactScaleAndOrientaiton(BaseImageDecoder.java:188)
10-22 18:19:26.190: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:76)
10-22 18:19:26.192: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:305)
10-22 18:19:26.193: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:251)
10-22 18:19:26.194: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:129)
10-22 18:19:26.195: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-22 18:19:26.195: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-22 18:19:26.195: I/dalvikvm(19464):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-22 18:19:26.197: I/View tag inside onLoadingComplete:(19464): image_item_grid_image
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464): null
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.considerExactScaleAndOrientaiton(BaseImageDecoder.java:188)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:76)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:305)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:251)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:129)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-22 18:19:26.204: E/ImageLoader(19464):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

UPDATE:

```
   @Override
   public void onPause(){
       super.onPause();
       imageLoader.pause();
   }

   @Override 
   public void onResume(){
       super.onResume();
       imageLoader.resume();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy(){
       super.onDestroy();
       imageLoader.stop();

   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to keep the Bitmaps and not reload it again and also have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @A.S. I am using unversal-image-loader sir.

Comment: Please check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958543/view-pager-with-universal-image-loader-out-of-memory-error

Comment: @RethinavelVelu already did sir

Comment: are you changing the device orientation?

Comment: @Droid The app will OOM when I change the orientation frequently to check how my app will respond.

Comment: perhaps the orientation change is restarting the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please edit your code to

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.content_picture)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.content_picture)

        .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
        .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity())
        .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, null)
        .threadPoolSize(5)
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
        .writeDebugLogs()
        .build();


        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().handleSlowNetwork(true);
```

Comment: I am using `@Override public Parcelable saveState() { return null; }`, what can you say about this? with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: I tried using this before but it destroys my UI ,I am using tab navigation, after orientation the tabs changes to dropdown list. The views is getting smaller. I am working with the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter ` and the `Parcelable saveState() ` to retain the fragments state after orientation.

Comment: Edited the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to recycle all the bitmaps. You can also call to the garbage collector like this System.gc();

Every time your app's orientation changes, it's reloading all the bitmaps again.

You could try to free memory in the onResume() which is called after the orientation change.

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Clean data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use following function to scale down the image,,so use result bitmap it wont rise out Of memory exception

public Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight,
                Context context) {

```
        final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int h = (int) (newHeight * densityMultiplier);
        int w = (int) (h * photo.getWidth() / ((double) photo.getHeight()));

        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: I can't scale down the images coz I intentionally use large images for zooming in. Thanks