# Loading Large Size Image Give Heap in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, heap-memory

I am downloading the image from server and store in sdcard but when i load the image from sdcard to imageview it gives heap memory.i also try with picasso library like below but same give heap.like this using picaso

image url which i download from server and store in sdcard just for example because i need to display image offline aswell

https://secure.peakmedia.at/studio/img/thumbnails/original/Gewalt-910.jpg

***UsingPicasso***

```
String path="/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201411031235020952.jpg";
        path=path.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        Picasso.with(TestActivity.this).load(uri).config(Config.RGB_565).into(imageview);
```

***TestActivity.java***

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {


    ImageView imageview;

     int nwidth;
     int nheight;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

        DisplayMetrics metrics=this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        nwidth=metrics.widthPixels;
        nheight=metrics.heightPixels;

        new SetImage().execute("/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201411031235020952.jpg");

    }


    public static Bitmap loadnewresize( String filename, int width, int height, boolean exact){

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename,options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        options.inDither = true;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename,options);      

    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }   

    return inSampleSize;
}

    private class SetImage extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap=loadnewresize(params[0], nwidth, nheight, false);
            return bitmap ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            imageview.setImageBitmap(result);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance; If you read [this](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/bfAFC5YZ3mq) post on G+ by Koush you will get clear solutions for your confusions, I have put the summery of that, in that  Android-Universal-Image-Loader is the winner for your requirement!

- **[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)** has the nicest image API if you are using network!
- **[UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) + [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)** is the fastest. Playing with these 
  other two great libraries have really highlighted that the image API 
  is quite dated, however.
- **[Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)** is slick; I really enjoy their pluggable backend transports,
  and may end up dropping AndroidAsync in there. The request priority
  and cancellation management is great(if you are using network)
- **[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** is the most popular one out there
  currently. Highly customizable.

> This project aims to provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous
>   image loading, caching and displaying. It is originally based on Fedor
>   Vlasov's project and has been vastly refactored and improved since
>   then.

Considering all this Android-Universal-Image-Loader suites your requirement (*Loading the images are on disk locally*)!

Comment: i also try with universalimageloader after your suggestion but still give heap

Comment: have you increased cache size ?

Comment: what should i change if i want to load morethan 2 to 5 mb image from sdcard

Comment: how much max can we give in cachesize ?

Comment: check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515303/out-of-memory-using-after-5-times-of-change-orientation)  post to overcome memory management

Comment: in this many options are deprecated like .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, null) .cacheOnDisc(true) but still give same heap